# Add a logo to the approval alert template

Tags: email-template, approval-process

Is it possible to add a logo (or otherwise customise) the standard Salesforce Approval Process e-mail template?

I have "Enable Email Approval Response" turned on in this org, and so I'm receiving the standard approval e-mail that looks like this:

[image: approval process]

Is there any way to stick the company logo (either directly, or from the org documents etc.) into this e-mail? I can't find the template/settings anywhere I look. I don't really want to have to duplicate the whole template and stick it into every approval process. (though I will if I have to, and duplicating it into unfiled templates isn't too hard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that my suspicions, Brad B and the docs are right, you cannot alter the default notification template. It has to be overridden. Therefore the solution to the question I posed (for those who come across this) is as follows.

First, I'd recommend you make the logo you want to include a public document in your salesforce org. This is best approached by clicking the "Documents" tab (which may be hidden under the tab + sign).

From there upload your logo file, to the Shared Documents folder, making it an `Externally Available Image`

[image: add a picture]

..then select and upload your file.

Putting this logo at the top of an e-mail can be done by creating a rich letterheaded e-mail, so click through **Setup > Communication Templates > Letterheads** click "New Letterhead" give it a name and label, make it "Available for use" and click to Save. In the letterhead editor, click "Select Logo" and then find your document in the popup.

[image: letterhead editor]

Save your letterhead.

Now navigate to e-mail templates, **Setup > Communication Templates > Email Templates** and click to create a new one. Select "HTML (using Letterhead)" and click next,

Fill in your folder, template name and pick your letterhead from the dropdown. Choose freeform letter (for the best approval process looking email) make sure it is available for use and "Next".

Now you can set a subject and body as follows:
(to mimic default behaviour)  )

With "Approval by email reply" **enabled** :

For the subject use `Salesforce record awaiting approval`

For the body:

```
{!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName} has requested your approval for 
the following item.
To approve or reject this item, reply to this email with
the word APPROVE, APPROVED, YES, REJECT, REJECTED, or NO
in the first line of the email message, or click this link:
 
{!ApprovalRequest.External_URL}
 
If replying via email you can also add comments on the 
second line. The comments will be stored with the approval 
request in Salesforce CRM.
Note: For salesforce.com to process your response the word 
APPROVE, APPROVED, YES, REJECT, REJECTED, or NO must be in 
the very first line of the reply email. Also, any comment
must be in the second line.
```

If you do not have the approve by e-mail feature on, use:

Subject: `Approval Request`

Body

```
{!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName} has requested your approval for the following item: {!ApprovalRequest.External_URL}

Please click this link to approve or reject this record.

Thank you,
salesforce.com
```

Paste the same text into the plain text body field too, this means if users mail clients don't support rich content, they still get the message body.

Then, you have your duplicate e-mail template set up, but with a logo.

To assign this to an approval process, through the browser navigate to the approval process in question and click on the "Edit" downarrow at the top, and choose notification template:

[image: notification template]

On this page, you can select your e-mail template (using the lookup dialogue) and, once saved, next time the record approval e-mail is dispatched, it will have a logo on it!!

(regarding updating all Approval processes to use this new template en masse, I can't advise right now. You will have to update each one through the browser).

Answer (score 2):

You can set a custom template on the Approval Detail Page. Click on the Edit button, then click Notification Templates. You can specify a template to use instead of the default one provided. On this template, you can add your desired org logo. According to Salesforce, you can only change the notification template, not modify the default. [Salesforce reference here](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=wf_approval_settings.htm&siteLang=en_US).

Comment: Hmm. I really didn't want to have to override the default notification template. But if that is the answer, that is the answer! (I will hold out on any other suggestions a bit before accepting the post :) )