# Salesforce approval process by replying to custom email template

Tags: email-template, approval-process

With the option 'Enable Email Approval Response' checked, you can approve to text email by replying 'Yes','No', 'APPROVE', 'REJECT',etc. 
Is possible to reply your approval or rejection on an email that has an html email template?

Thanks, 
Nawshine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. It allows using Letter head email templates, even if it is not specified in the documentation.

Comment: @Bartley was this intended for the other answer?

Comment: While this is an answer, it'd be better if it game a little more info :)

Comment: Thanks all. I made a test to ensure that it was indeed the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can do it with custom email Template.

The only thing you need to take care of is email template should contain the appropriate information with the **link to Approve page**

Go throuth [Enable Email Approve Response](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_email.htm&language=en_US) this link

Hope this information will help you out to resolve your query.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I went through it initially and it did not specify for custom email template. I made a test to verify. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by creating a rich letterheaded e-mail. You can find the process in detail in this SFSE link. [Add a logo to the approval alert template](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31548/add-a-logo-to-the-approval-alert-template)